# Summary by CLRProfiler: Heap Statistics values are 0

Tags: clrprofiler

I am using CLRProfiler, 64bit for .NET 4.

I am attaching CLRProfiler to a running iis worker-process running a single website.

All values in the Summary-view are always zero.

Only Heap Dumps has a value of 1 and I can see the Heap Graph.

Only if I attach to an exe using 'Profile Application' will I get any values in the Summary-view.

Does anybody have an idea why the Summary-view has no values?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to profile a windows service recently and was running into the same issue.
I had neglected to check of the Allocations box prior to starting up my service.  After doing that, I started seeing a lot more info regarding allocated bytes and collections.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376436/clr-profiler-and-0-heap-statistics).