# CLR Profiler and 0 Heap Statistics

Tags: .net, iis, clr, heap-memory, clrprofiler

Why would I get 0 for my heap statistics allocation for an ASP.NET MVC web application with CLR profiler?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was getting zeroes, but I think doing these two things solved the issue of zeroes: make sure you have "Allocations" checked in the "Profile" section and be sure to end the application before trying to see the profiling info. Either end it through CLR Profiler ("Kill Application") or from within the application itself. I believe both of those things were required to make it work for me.

Comment: Checking "Allocations" is also required if you want to trace calls.